# Running a simple Hello World program

Tags: java

I made a simple hello world program which just makes a window pop up with the title being "hello world". I want to know, What do I give to someone if I want them to run it like a normal java program? Would a .class file be enough?

do I just take the .class file and try to open it with java?

Here is the code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class hellobox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Hello world!");
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

I'm so sorry for such a pathetic question. first time fiddling with java.

Comment: Are you using an IDE to make this?  You want to compile it to a .jar file, then anybody with java installed can run it like an executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using eclipse, you could do this:

1. Right click your project
2. Click Export
3. Select Java
4. Select Runnable Jar File
5. Select the Launch Configuration (would usually be the name of your
   project or class that contains the main method
6. Choose the path to save the jar file to
7. Click Finish

That's it. Now you get a `.jar` file which can be run like a normal executable file on every computer which has Java installed. Regardless of the operation system.

Just passing the `.class` file would suffice, but it would force the other user to launch it via command line using `java MyClassName` (without the .class suffix)

Comment: I right click my project, dont get any option that says "java". Maybe I'm clicking the wrong thing.

Comment: Sorry, missed a stage. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

You only need a .class file.  You don't need a JAR file or an IDE or Maven.

Follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) to the letter.  You'll get it to run.

Comment: hi, what I have is different then what they are showing you. I have a box pop up with a title of "hello world" they just make the console print that. I want to know how I can run the program so it just makes a box with the title "hello world" without using eclipse. Understand my question?

Comment: Do I understand your question?  Yes, I know how to run "Hello World".  Sorry, the link wasn't what I thought it was.  I'll post something that should be better.  Try the new link.

Answer (score 0):

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is a very popular tool for managing building and packaging java applications.

For example, set up your POM and use this command to make a JAR file.

```
mvn package
```

Once you have a jar file, you can run it using java.

```
java path/to/MyHelloWorld.jar
```

Comment: Good lord, they're asking about hello world and you're offering Maven?

Comment: No, it's not.  I despise it for its complexity.  It's the last thing I'd recommend to anyone, especially a new person.